# How to send a String as a response in my SpringBoot API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I have the following POST endpoint in my API (Spring Boot):

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> createPartner(@RequestBody Partner partner) {
     Optional<Partner> partnerFound = 
          partnerRepository.findPartnerByPartnerCode(partner.getPartnerCode());
     if(partnerFound.isPresent()) {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
               .body("The informed partner code has already been registered on the database.");
     }
     return new ResponseEntity<>(partnerRepository.save(partner), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And this is the Partner object that I send on Postman:

```
{
    "partnerName": "Company ABC",
    "partnerCode": "ABC"
}
```

**When the partner code hasn't been registered on the database (and therefore it doesn't get in the if statement), the response is ok, and I get the following response:**

[image]

**However, when I send the same object in the body (so it should return the message "The informed partner code has already been registered on the database." in the body), I get this error:**

[image]

Which says: "Response cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

This is my Partner object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Partner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "partner_name")
    private String partnerName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "partner_code")
    private String partnerCode;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status = "Active";

    // getters and setters, equals, hashcode, to String...
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try replacing return type ResponseEntity<?> to ResponseEntity<Object>

Comment: The better way will be send info about error in response header instead of body.